# Submit button is not getting clicked after executing the selenium script

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

The Submit button is not getting clicked after executing the selenium script.I have attached the screenshot of the code.

[image: Click here to see the code]

Comment: Post code instead of pictures of it.

Comment: Can you paste the same code in text format.

Comment: @Aman Do not post the code with screenshot. Try to format the code and then include the exception/errors you received.
Be specific and brief about your need.
You find the following link to know about 
[How to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can introduce explicit wait. Something like this should do the Job.

```
 new WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("websubmit"))).click();
```

I'm using **name** attribute over **xpath** because of **stability** and precedence given.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

To improve overall script, you can add implicit wait for your entire webdriver instance. Currently I can see no wait is there for any element so in future your script may fail if any element get stuck/delayed in loading.

Try using - 
`fd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` Add this wait after your **webdriver** instance creation.